# Dynamically enable / disable Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to toggle ON/OFF my Fancybox
I can't find how to !

I tried $("#element").unbind('click.fb')
But it did not work...

Here is my example : http://jsfiddle.net/gbTZn/23/

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

What about simply having a switch around the default preventDefault method?

i.e.

```
var isFBActive = true;
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
.. after your FB initilisation code ..
$('.yourimageclass').click(function (e) { if (!isFBActive) {e.preventDefault();} });
});
```